# Knockback effect with top down graphics on box2d

Tags: java, c++, box2d, physics, jbox2d

I'm currently making a top down gfx actiong RPG on java, using jbox2d. Basically I want the enemies to recoil back after they get hit by the player (with top down graphics I don't have friction or gravity). I tried with restitution, applying impulse and setting linear velocity but I didn't get what I expected: the enemies teleport to the destination istantly and if they are near the wall they get ported out of the map. How can I fix this and what is the best to do it in your opinion? thanks a lot

Comment: Why the C++ tag? Also provide us the code of the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are using jbox2d and c++ at the same time...

Regardless, if your enemies are represented physically by `b2_dynamicBody`s then you probably want to [apply a linear impulse](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html#ada3c2a70cbb53c4fcee5a4febbbefc15) and set the [linear damping](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html#a909f9753ad700f70282a56e00bc182a5) of the enemy body to a value greater than zero. Linear damping works like air drag - The faster the object is moving, the larger the force applied in the opposite direction. Applying a large linear impulse and setting a high linear damping will cause your enemies to fly away from your hero with a very high initial velocity, but they will come to rest very quickly.

I hope this helps!